# Latency when playing audio over bluetooth

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, pulse-audio

I'm trying to solve the same problem described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145935/get-rid-of-0-5s-latency-when-playing-audio-over-bluetooth-with-a2dp. To lower the latency of audio when played on a bluetooth device.

When I connect a bluetooth device to listen to audio (e.g. bluetooth headphones), the sound arrives with a delay (ca 0.5 s). I'm working with an embedded device.

I already tried all the solution listed there, but none of those have worked for me. I also tried to follow the steps lisetd here: https://juho.tykkala.fi/Pulseaudio-and-latency but with no success.

The exact procedure that I follow is:

1. Connect bluetooth device (via bluetoothctl)
2. Load some modules into PulseAudio (pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:2,0)
3. Load a loopback module to address the sound to the headohones (pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.hw_2_0 sink=bluez_sink.30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D.a2dp_sink)

Additional infos:

I MUST use pulseAudio.
I'm pretty sure I can solve this issue removing the card of the bluetooth device and reloading it with different parameters (as showed in the 2nd link), but I have no idea about how can I accomplish it for a bluez card.

Using

pactl list cards

gives

```
Card #0
    Name: bluez_card.30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 20
    Properties:
        device.description = "JBL T450BT"
        device.string = "30:C0:1B:E4:CF:8D"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci1/dev_30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "JBL T450BT"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: a2dp_sink
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
        headset-input: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
```

and

pactl list sinks

```
Sink #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: bluez_sink.30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D.a2dp_sink
    Description: JBL T450BT
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 20
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: bluez_sink.30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D.a2dp_sink.monitor
    **Latency: 49696 usec, configured 39512 usec  <-- HERE THE PROBLEM**
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "JBL T450BT"
        device.string = "30:C0:1B:E4:CF:8D"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci1/dev_30_C0_1B_E4_CF_8D"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "JBL T450BT"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority: 0, available)
    Active Port: headset-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Any tips? Thanks